# Multiple Instances instead of copies of interface

Tags: java

So this might be a little difficult to explain...

At the moment i do this:

```
SomeInterface xyz1 = SomeInterface.method(data);
SomeInterfaceCopy xyz2 = SomeInterfaceCopy.method(data);
```

What i have done here is make an exact copy of 
every class and interface of 'SomeInterface',
because i need two 'instances' of the same
interface.

What i would like to do is something like this:

```
SomeInterface xyz1 = SomeInterface.method(data);
SomeInterface xyz2 = SomeInterface.method(data);
```

This would allow me to have more than two 'instances',
it is not possible atm because xyz1 and xyz2 are basically
copies (all objects within the same instance)
of each other instead of instances.

How would i go about achieving this?

Thank you :)

edit: Thank you @PeterLawrey, unfortunately it doesn't solve my specific problem, but it is the right answer

Comment: There's [nothing stopping you doing the 2nd example](https://ideone.com/mjkxwo). I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't want two different interfaces which are copies of each other, don't use the copied interface, just use the original one.

Comment: the problem is, that all the objects and data within, is the same when i use the second example

Comment: If you don't want the result to be the same you need to change the implementation of the method, not the API.

Comment: I'm guessing you want a deep copy rather than a shallow one?

Comment: @SnakeyHips, you would be correct

Comment: @PeterLawrey, unfortunately, I can't do that... that would be the easiest way to go.
It's a existing code base... much like a jenga tower... so i can only extend, not change very much. Also this Problem is really difficult to explain (non native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two interfaces which are the same, but for some reason, you can't easily just remove the duplicate interface and not use it.

```
SomeInterface xyz1 = SomeInterface.method(data);
SomeInterfaceCopy xyz2 = SomeInterfaceCopy.method(data);
```

The simplest change is to make the copy inherit from the original.

```
interface SomeInterfaceCopy extends SomeInterface {
```

This means you can write either

```
SomeInterfaceCopy xyz2 = SomeInterfaceCopy.method(data);
```

or

```
SomeInterface xyz2 = SomeInterfaceCopy.method(data);
```

If you can't change the code at all, but instead want a deep copy, field by field, you can look at a serialization of the original object and deserialize it as the target type.

> could you give an example of calling new twice please?

Say `class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface` you can create two instances with

```
SomeInterface xyz1 = new SomeInterfaceImpl(); // one instance
SomeInterface xyz2 = new SomeInterfaceImpl(); // 2nd instance.
```

Comment: Thank you, it's really close.. but it wouldn't allow me to haw a xyz3 or 4 or however many instances or deep copies i would need.

Comment: @heycaptain yes, you would need to do something to remove all the duplication which doesn't appear to be gaining you anything, or you need to do a deep copy.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to post this much.
 I implemented the duplication, as a quick and dirty way of getting two instances of the interface. However there will be the need to get more than two in the near future.

Is there a way of generating a clone of an instance? (haven't found anything)

Comment: @heycaptain You can use `clone()` however you have to implement `Cloneable` and override it for deep copies.

Comment: @heycaptain can have two instances of an interface by calling `new` twice on a concrete class which implements it. No need to copy the interface as it's a template.

Comment: could you give an example of calling new twice please?

Comment: @heycaptain I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make a deep copy of an object is to create a new instance of the class with your own deep copy constructor within that class. So for the copy constructor:

```
public Class(Class class) {
 this(class.getFirstProp(),customer.getSecondProp());
}
```

Then use it like:

```
Class a = new Class(data.firstvalue, data.secondvalue);
Class b = new Class(a);
```

Comment: It's an interface, not a class